# Hover text on select options

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a drop down list in my form.

I want to show its title attribute value on hovering each option.

Issue here is in IE title is displaying only 5 seconds but intended behavior should display title as long as I move the cursor out of option.

So I have used Bootstrap tooltip and popover but those are not working with select option element.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select id="testList">
            <option value="1" title="Header1" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" style="color:red;">Item 1</option>
            <option value="2" title="Header2" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" style="color:green;">Item 2</option>
            <option value="3" title="Header3" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" style="">Item 3</option>
            <option value="4" title="Header4" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" style="color:orange;">Item 4</option>
        </select>

    </div>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        });


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried multiple things and gone through many SOF Q & As but not able to achieve the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").hover(function (e)
{
     var $target = $(e.target); 
     if($target.is('option')){
         alert($target.attr("id"));//Will alert id if it has id attribute
         alert($target.text());//Will alert the text of the option
         alert($target.val());//Will alert the value of the option
     }
});
```

Comment: Intended behavior is not alert box, should show some thing like tooltip

Answer (score 0):

We have to tweak a little bit to make it work. We can't directly add a tool tip to select option. 
Instead we can apply chosen plugin on select box, it converts the select options to unordered list. on top of that we can add tool tip on each li element.

```
$("#testList").chosen({                    
                    disable_search: true

});

$("testList_chosen.li.active-result").each(function(){
                $(this).attr('data-toggle','tooltip');
});

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
```

Read more about chosen plug in here.
    http://julesjanssen.github.io/chosen/